# Sending an xml file from java application and reading it in jsp

Tags: java, xml, jsp, post, httpclient

I have a java application containing main method. If I am passing an xml file using Httpclient's post method to a jsp file on the server side, how can I get it and read it in the jsp file from request object? I know there is a way to get the xml file in the servlet, but,  is there any way to get it in the jsp file?

Answer (score -1):

the same way in servlet will work in the jsp scriptlet as well.
Share the code for better understanding

[How to extract value from this XML in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16034437/how-to-extract-value-from-this-xml-in-jsp)

Comment: in the given example you have the xml path. I don't have any. Client will be sending me xml through http request. Parsing is not an issue. Getting the xml file from the request object in the jsp is the issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595173/multipart-requests-responses-java
}` try this code and check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595173/multipart-requests-responses-java)